# This app is not available for your phone because it requires front facing camera

Tags: camera, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

We have developed an app using Xamarin Forms which targets iOS, Android and Windows Phone. We are using camera feature to take/select photos to be uploaded to the app and the feature works well on all three mentioned platforms.

We have some users facing issues on few windows devices. When a user tries to download the app from Windows App Store, they receive following error:

*"This app is not available for your phone because it requires front facing camera”*

I have attached [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHJNb.png) showing the error for reference. The screen shot is taken from Nokia Lumia 635. Our finding that this device has only back camera, no front camera and we believe this might be the reason for above mentioned issue.

Ideally, users should not get this error as this device has back camera and they still can get the photos.

Is this a known issue in windows phone world?
Can this be fixed from code, device permissions?
Is this a device specific problem?

Any ideas?